# Cropping from the top and bottom of an image using ImageCrop

Tags: image-processing, documentation

Under details and options the documentation article ref/ImageCrop says:

> The cropping specification spec in ImageCrop[image, size, spec] can have the following forms:
>
> {side1, side2} ... crops on the specified sides

and

> Sides can be specified as Left, Right, Bottom, or Top. Center indicates symmetrical cropping.

and yet

```
ImageCrop[image, 2, {Top, Bottom}]
```

produces the message

> {Top, Bottom} is not a list of two numbers or two valid symbolic cropping values.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 8):

The documentation could be more clear I think, and the syntax message isn't very helpful.  I believe the specifications must be `Left` *or* `Right`, `Bottom` *or* `Top`.  So for example:

```
img = Image[DiamondMatrix[50]]

ImageCrop[img, {70, 70}, {Left, Top}]
```

[image]

[image]

If you want symmetrical top-and-bottom cropping use `Center`:

```
ImageCrop[img, {70, 70}, {Right, Center}]
```

[image]

Or specify fractions explicitly:

```
ImageCrop[img, {70, 70}, {-2/3, 0}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I agree that the documentation of `ImageCrop` is not nearly as clear as it could be.

What you are missing is that the 3rd argument, the ***side*** specification, must relate to the 2nd argument, the ***size*** specification. The size spec is always given in the form

```
{width_crop, height_crop}
```

so giving

```
{Top, Bottom}
```

is rejected because `Top` can not be related to the width of the image.

To crop a certain number of pixels off from both the top and the bottom of an while leaving the width alone, we must coordinate the size spec with the side spec.  Consider removing 25 pixels both the top and the bottom of the following image.

[image]

One way is to write

```
With[{pxls = 25, img = < image >},
  ImageCrop[img, {Full, ImageDimensions[img][[2]] - 2 pxls}, Center]]
```

where `< image >` is the image shown above. This produces

[image: cropped]

Comment: The last operation could be done more cleanly with `ImageTake[img, {26, -26}]`.  That doesn't teach one about `ImageCrop` of course, other than it's best to start with the right tool.  +1 for making the edge specification explicit; I meant to imply that but reading again I see there is still room for confusion in what I wrote.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard.1) I agree that it might be better to use `ImageTake`, but I think it is quite natural for users to turn to `ImageCrop` when they want to crop an image. 2) I would not of posted this answer if I hadn't thought your answer needed some clarification.